# reference a value outside of the request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want to acceed to the variable JSON.parse(body) but not in the callback function of the function request. How i can do this ?
Here is my code:

```
request('https://' + region + '.api.pvp.net/api/lol/' + region + '/v2.5/league/by-summoner/' + id + '/entry?api_key=' + APIKEY, function(error, response, body) {
    return JSON.parse(body)
})
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `return` from callbacks like this, and you can't access the value of an asynchronous operation until after it completes so you need some method of synchronization.  One is continuation passing:

```
function callback(body) {
    // use body
}

request(url, (err, response, body) => {
  // handle error

  callback(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i can't set leagueEntry = body with this ? var leagueEntry;
      function callback(body) {
        leagueEntry = body
      }
      request(url, (err, response, body) => {
        callback(JSON.parse(body))
      })

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a variable by saying

```
var Parsedbody = request('https://'...) ({
  return JSON.parse(body); });
```

or you could define a variable before the request and assign it within the request eg.

```
var ParsedBody;
request('https://'...) ({
  ParsedBody = JSON.parse(body); });
```